# how to combine recursive feature elimination and grid/random search inside one CV loop?

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I've seen taught several places that feature selection needs to be inside the CV training loop.  Here are three examples where I have seen this:

[Feature selection and cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750/feature-selection-and-cross-validation/27751#27751)

[Nested cross-validation and feature selection: when to perform the feature selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223740/nested-cross-validation-and-feature-selection-when-to-perform-the-feature-selec)

https://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/

> ...you must include feature selection within the inner-loop when you
>   are using accuracy estimation methods such as cross-validation. This
>   means that feature selection is performed on the prepared fold right
>   before the model is trained. A mistake would be to perform feature
>   selection first to prepare your data, then perform model selection and
>   training on the selected features...

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) is an example from the sklearn docs, that shows how to do recursive feature elimination with regular n-fold cross validation.

However I'd like to do recursive feature elimination inside random/grid CV, so that "feature selection is performed on the prepared fold right before the model is trained (on the random/grid selected params for that fold)", so that data from other folds influence neither feature selection nor hyperparameter optimization.

Is this possible natively with sklearn methods and/or pipelines?  Basically, I'm trying to find an sklearn native way to do this before I go code it from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search over the number of features to retain, then you need some sort of cross-validation, and since as you point out this needs to be done inside the training set of the main model fit, this will require nested cross-validation.  If that's not a computational problem for you, then sklearn makes this pretty simple.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('feat_sel', RFECV(...)),
                       # ...other preprocessing?...
                       ('model', LogisticRegression(...)) # or whatever
                      ])
search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe, ...)
search.fit(X, y)
```

Note that you could provide your own cross-validation instead of the default k-fold, if you need to save some computation time.

The other option is to use `RFE` instead of `RFECV`, which requires a fixed number of features to use, but then doesn't need its own cross-validation; this seems best if you have some domain or previous model information to suggest the right number of features in advance (be sure not to use *your* whole training set to determine that!).

Comment: Thank you @Ben Rein, that's the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Randomized/Grid search CV you can also use the simple [`RFE`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464312/how-to-combine-recursive-feature-elimination-and-grid-random-search-inside-one-c) without nesting another CV inside the main one. In this case, you should specify among the parameters searched during the grid/randomized search also the number of features that you want to test in order to find the optimal one. Combining this RFE with the machine-learning algorithm of your choice in a pipeline, will allow you to use the selected features during the fit phase that will be performed on the same set of data used by the RFE. I repropose here the same example in Ben's answer with the here proposed method:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('feat_sel', RFE(estimator=..., step=1)),
                       # ...other preprocessing?...
                       ('model', LogisticRegression(...)) # or whatever
                      ]
               )
param_distributions = {
                       # specify here the number of features you want to test using the RFE method
                       'feat_sel__n_features_to_select': [4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
                       # ... other parameters you want to search ...
                      }

search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                            param_distributions=param_distributions, ...)
search.fit(X, y)
```